# Как можно использовать результат процедуры в select в MSSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Как можно использовать результат процедуры в select в MSSQL?
Может быть как то во временную таблицу запихнуть результат работы процедуры(но это вроде такая же обычная таблица, нет?)
Или как то создать временную переменную и туда записать значение?

И нужен результат не всей таблицы из процедуры, а лишь некоторые столбцы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат из хранимой процедуры в (временную) таблицу:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable   
EXECUTE MyStoregeProc;
```

[Пример](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/05/27/sql-server-how-to-insert-data-from-stored-procedure-to-table-2-different-methods/)

Comment: Только не забыть добавить # перед MyTable